# How do I install SRILM on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, tools

SRILM is a tool for Language Modelling in Natural Language Processing (NLP), http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/

There is no clear installation guide to install SRILM on ubuntu 14.04. There was one for 11.10 but it is outdated and it doesn't work properly. http://www.spencegreen.com/2012/02/01/installing-srilm-on-ubuntu-11-10/

**Does anyone know how to install SRILM on Ubuntu 14.04?**

Answer (score 4):

I have already installed to srilm on Ubuntu 14.04. Following are the commands:

```
mkdir /usr/share/srilm
mv srilm.tgz /usr/share/srilm
cd /usr/share/srilm
tar xzf srilm.tgz
```

In the Makefile, uncomment the `SRILM=` parameter and point it to `/usr/share/srilm` (or your equivalent path).

The run the following commands in Supper user mode:

```
tcsh
make NO_TCL=1 MACHINE_TYPE=i686-gcc4 World (if you are using 64 bit system then i686 to replace with x86_64)
./bin/i686-gcc4/ngram-count -help
```

Comment: I'm getting `/usr/share/srilm/common/Makefile.common.variables:105: /usr/share/srilm/common/Makefile.machine.x86_64-gcc4: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/share/srilm/common/Makefile.machine.x86_64-gcc4'.  Stop.
`

Comment: `MACHINE_TYPE=i686-m64` should be used... not x86_64. Just read installation instruction in INSTALL file

Comment: Could this be added to the post above?

Comment: I am getting this. 
make NO_TCL=1 MACHINE_TYPE=i686-m64 World
make: *** No rule to make target 'World'.  Stop.

Answer (score 1):

Download and anpack tgz-file (e.g. from [moses-suite](https://code.google.com/p/moses-suite/downloads/detail?name=srilm-1.6.0.tar.gz&can=2&q=) and then follow instructions in INSTALL text document with installation instruction. After successful `make`-ing process do not forget to update `export PATH` with path that includes `$MACHINE_TYPE` (it is all described in the INSTALL).