# Installation of SRILM on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I am trying to install srilm-1.6.0 on Release 12.04 (32-bit, Kernel Linux 3.5.0-41-generic) that is run on virtual machine (VirtualBox 4.3.12 r93733)
`gcc -v` said that it is `gcc version 4.6.3`.

I have read [How do I install SRILM on ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507659/how-do-i-install-srilm-on-ubuntu-14-04) but it does not help

The commands

```
 make World
```

and

```
 make MACHINE_TYPE=i686 World
```

and

```
 make MACHINE_TYPE=i686-m64 World
```

lead to error message

```
 make: /sbin/machine-type: Command not found
 Makefile:13: /common/Makefile.common.variables: No such file or directory
 make: *** No rule to make target `/common/Makefile.common.variables'.  Stop.
```

What I did wrond and what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the post about ubuntu 14.04 read INSTALL file carefully. E.g.:

2 - Set the SRILM variable in the top-level Makefile to point to this
    top-level directory (an absolute path).

Comment: Now I can start the make, but other error is "tclmain.cc:8:17: fatal error: tcl.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated." And `apt-get install tcl` didn't help

Comment: Use `apt-get install tcl-dev` and do not forget to insert path to tcl.h (e.g. -I/usr/include/tcl8.5) to `TCL_INCLUDE` in `common/Makefile.machine.<your platform>`